# Saving data to device with parse

Tags: android, sqlite, parse-platform, android-contentprovider

Planning to save data locally, I have created a ContentProvider backed by a SQLite data base. But now that I am deciding to use Parse instead of App Engine, do I still need my own SQLite-ContentProvider to persist data locally? Or can I configure Parse to fetch some data to the device so user can have offline access? And by offline, I do not mean in-memory: I do mean available even after the app is destroyed: sqlite style.

With App Engine the server would use an algorithm to decide what data to make available offline (for argument say its “trending” data). Can I still do that with Parse? My whole ContentProvider is already created and paired with an SyncAdapter so as to sync the “trending” data periodically. How would something like this work with Parse? I want to take full advantage of the conveniences of Parse, so I don’t really want to do things Parse itself can do for me. I hope the question is clear and is not too much for a response. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find the answers to your questions on the [Official Parse documentation](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#objects-the-local-datastore).

You'll have to `Parse.enableLocalDatastore()` before calling `Parse.initialize()`, after just use `foo.pinInBackground();` when you wish to persist locally.

Regarding the SQLite question: [Yes](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#objects-retrieving-objects-from-the-local-datastore)

Example:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("GameScore");
query.fromLocalDatastore();
query.getInBackground("xWMyZ4YEGZ", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
      // object will be your game score
    } else {
      // something went wrong
    }
  }
});
```

**I do recommend you to read the full guide.**